# Can I use get/set method inside a incoming new object generated by Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, class

This is my class, for example :

```
public class Point
{
    public string Min { get; set; }
    public string Max { get; set; }

    public Point()
    {

    }
}
```

and I'm building dynamic objects through linq to xml :

```
var list = xDoc.Descendants("item").Select(item => new
{
    NewPoint = new Point()
});
```

Now, I'd like to associate for each `NewPoint` the value `item.Min` and `item.Max`.

Such as `NewPoint.Min = item.Min` and `NewPoint.Max = item.Max`, without creating a Class constructor with 2 param in the method.

Is it possible? Hope the question is clear...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean a simple `n => new
{
    Point = new Point { Min = "1", Max = "10" }
}` ?

Comment: No, the question really isn't clear. Where is `item.Min` meant to be coming from? Why are Min and Max strings instead of numbers? Why are you creating an anonymous type for no obvious reason?

Comment: item.Min come from linq! Min and Max are not int for further motivation :)

Comment: No need for a down vote. I upvoted you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object initializer:

```
Point = new Point() { Min = n["min"], Max = n["max"] }
```

(or however you get your values out of `n`)

Alternatively, you can put a whole code block in your `Select`:

```
.Select(n => {
    var point = new Point();
    point.Min = n["min"];
    point.Max = n["max"];
    return new { Point = point };
});
```

---

Also note: unless you're selecting other things as well, you don't need

```
n => new { Point = new Point() }
```

You can just use `n => new Point()` and end up with an `IEnumerable<Point>` rather than an `IEnumerable<AnonymousClassContainingPoint>`.

Comment: Oh, I see you already mentioned selecting only `Point`s... Should have read your answer better, before posting mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = xDoc.Descendants("item").Select(n => new
{
    Point = new Point()
    {
       Min = n.Min,
       Max = n.Max,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just simplify the linq if you only want a list with `Point`s:

```
var list = xDoc.Descendants("item").Select(item => 
    new Point { Min = item.Min, Max = item.Max });
```